# Venn diagram for given data

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Out of $14$, $12$ people says that it was not the case that they watched T.V. but did not listen to the radio. Also for $9$ people it is not the case that they do not watch T.V. and do not listen to the radio. Finally there are $7$ people who either watch T.V. or listen to the radio but do not do both. Create a Venn diagram to show the above data.

I am not able to interpret the given data. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Define four variables $A,B,C,D$, where each represents the number of people surveyed that…

```
    listen to radio?
              yes no
watch TV? yes|  A  B
           no|  C  D
```

Then we have
$$A+B+C+D=14$$
$$A+C+D=12\implies B=2$$
$$A+B+C=9\implies D=5$$
$$B+C=7\implies C=5,A=2$$
Hence the Venn diagram you want can be drawn as follows.

```
   ---- ----
  /    X    \
 /    / \    \
|  2 | 2 | 5  |  5
 \    \ /    /
  \    X    /
   ---- ----
watch     listen to
   TV     radio
```

Answer (score 0):

set $T:=\{x|\text{x watches T.V}\}$, and $R:=\{x|\text{x listens to the radio}\}$.

$12=|(T\cap R^c)^c|.$ So  $14-12=|T\cap R^c|$.
$9=|(T^c\cap R^c)^c|=|T\cup R|,$ and $7=|(T\cup R)|- |(T\cap R)|.$ So $14-9=|(T\cup R)^c|;$   Also $9-7=|(T\cap R)|.$
Therefore $9-4=|R\cap T^c|$.

[image]